# manifest.json возвращает noscript

Tags: javascript, html, manifest, pwa

У меня есть сайт [KinoFinder](https://kinofinder.rf.gd). При первом запуске (или ctrl + F5) В консоли такая ошибка:

> manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

Если ввести в адресную строку [kinofinder.rf.gd/manifest.json](https://kinofinder.rf.gd/manifest.json), то мне выдает мой манифест.
А если посмотреть в devTools network, что возвращает запрос на /manifest.json, то выдает сообщение, о том, что javascript не поддерживается

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Вот мой html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="Description" content="some description">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#da931b">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="KinoFinder">
  <meta name="application-name" content="KinoFinder">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#464646">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#464646 ">
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon " sizes="180x180" href="/assets/icons/180x18 0.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png " sizes="32x32" href="/assets/icons/32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png " sizes="16x16" href="/assets/icons/16x16.png">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/assets/icons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#ff9000">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/icons/favicon.ico">
  <title>KinoFinder</title>
  </head><body><div id="root"></div><script src="index.afea4cc6ceceb520192b.js"></script></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо относительного пути к manifest укажите абсолютный. Возможно у Вас сначала подгружается файл манифеста, а уже потом Javascript. Это и приводит к ошибке при первой загрузке. После загрузки файла в кэш, браузер будет показывать кэшированные данные даже при изменении их на сервере. Для обновления кэша в браузере необходимо изменить сам файл манифеста. Более подробно можно посмотреть здесь: https://domhtml.ru/atribut-manifest-dlya-tega-html/

Comment: Да, вообще всегда лучше использовать относительные пути

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в подключении манифеста по относительной ссылке.

Исправте

```
   <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

на

```
   <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

Comment: Забыл написать ,что я пробовал и со слэшем, и без, и так ./. Но это не сработало

Comment: все равно, со слешем будет правильнее (причем без точек вначале/конце), либо еще лучше вообще с полной прямой ссылкой. Надо искать ошибку дальше

Comment: Ну это понятно. Но ответа на сам вопрос нет. Почему манифест загружается и возвращает noscript??

Comment: Да причем тут noscript? Манифест пытается загрузиться и сервер вместо манифеста сует браузеру страницу 404. Вот браузер и ругается на первый символ в манифесте.

Comment: Но потом манифест кэшируется. И при последующих перезагрузка все нормально. Я так понимаю ,что манифест просто то ли слишком поздно загружается, то ли что-то вроде этого. Но он есть. 404 не может быть

Comment: Ну так вроде бы и не 404. Но откуда эта страница вообще берется? Может быть, хостинг чудит? я такое первый раз вижу!

Comment: Если написать https://kinofinder.rf.gd/manifest.json, то всё работает. Проверьте сами